# Searching for questions without a tag

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to search for questions without a tag?

ps: I tried *-[tagname]* and *NOT [tagname]* but they don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible for questions to have no tags. All questions must have at least one tag.

There are background processes that cull single-use tags that are more than 6 months old, but even then we retag the question to [untagged](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

I see -- you want something else, "show me questions without this tag". Try this blog post.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

However, bear in mind that "NOT something", by itself, is disallowed. You must have "something and NOT something else"

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but that is not my question. I don't want to search for questions which do not have any tags, I want to search for *questions which say are not tagged with [ds.algorithms]*. Is that possible?

Comment: Similarly, is it possible to search for question which do not contain some phrase? Something like Google's - operator, e.g. [-"ds.algorithms" site:cstheory.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.ca/search?q=-%22ds.algorithms%22+site%3Acstheory.stackexchange.com). (ps: the problem with using Google and Bing is that the results are not very accurate and contain false positives and negatives).

Comment: Here is [an example](http://www.bing.com/search?q=-%22cc.complexity-theory%22+-%22ds.algorithms%22+-computability+-%22lo.logic%22+-%22pl.programming-lang%22+-%22co.combinatorics%22+-%22cr.crypto-security%22+-%22fl.formal-languages%22+-%22cg.comp-geom%22+-%22lg.learning%22+site%3Acstheory.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions) from Bing which is not correct. It should at least return some questions from [tag-removed](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-removed) but does not not return any.

Comment: And Google [returns](http://www.google.com/search?q=-%22cc.complexity-theory%22+-%22ds.algorithms%22+-computability+-%22lo.logic%22+-%22pl.programming-lang%22+-%22co.combinatorics%22+-%22cr.crypto-security%22+-%22fl.formal-languages%22+-%22cg.comp-geom%22+-%22lg.learning%22+site%3Acstheory.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions) too many false results.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the link to the blog post. That answers my question. :)